# Listing message IDs and names stored in an unmanaged resource library DLL using C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

We would like to list the contents (key/value pairs) of an unmanaged resource library (DLL) in C#.
(Please note, the resource DLL is **NOT** a .Net assembly/DLL)

The resource library is defined as specified [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
mc -s EventLogMsgs.mc
rc EventLogMsgs.rc
link /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /NOENTRY /MACHINE:x86 EventLogMsgs.Res
```

A sample EventLogMsgs.mc may be:

```
; // - Event categories -
; // Categories must be numbered consecutively starting at 1.
; // ********************************************************

MessageId=0x1
Severity=Success
SymbolicName=INSTALL_CATEGORY
Language=English
Installation
.

MessageId=0x2
Severity=Success
SymbolicName=QUERY_CATEGORY
Language=English
Database Query
.

...
```

If this resource library DLL were a .Net assembly DLL, listing the resources would be done using something along these lines:

```
string strResourceDLLPath = "c:\\temp\\EventLogMsgs.DLL";

Assembly resAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( strResourceDLLPath );
ResourceManager resMgr = new ResourceManager( "ResourcesLib.Messages", resAssembly );
ResourceSet resSet = resMgr.GetResourceSet( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true );

foreach (DictionaryEntry r in resSet)
    Console.WriteLine( "Key={0} Value={1}", r.Key.ToString(), r.Value.ToString() );
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ResourceManager` is for managed resources.

Comment: Agreed, ResourceManager can NOT be used for this purpose. The code snippet was just a demonstration of what we're trying to achieve for a non-managed resource.

Comment: I think you have to use the win32 api.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242578/how-to-findresource-pinvoke-a-string-resource-in-c), it has sample of how to load resource from unmanaged dll using imported win32 API functions.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122552/listing-message-ids-and-symbolic-names-stored-in-a-resource-only-library-dll-u) contains a win32 API solution for listing the message details in a resource-only DLL.

In order to be able to do the same in C#, P/Invoke would have to be utilized.